# Passing on a list of arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to pass on a list of arguments to sprintf which apparently doens't pick them up. What am i missing?

```
void respond( const char *format, ...) {
  char buffer[256];
  va_list args;
  int len, retCode;

  va_start( args, format);
  len = sprintf( buffer, format, args);
  va_end( args);

  retCode = send( newSockFD, buffer, len, 0);
  if( retCode == -1) error( "Could not write to socket");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf can not work with varable argument so use

**vsnprintf()**

```
 len = vsnprintf( buffer, sizeof(buffer),format, args);
```

Comment: After seeing these i learnt its not how fast you show him the path its how you make him understand :)

Comment: ;) well but after seeing question i just write code for that...rather then finding links for that function in google..!!!

Answer (score 6):

Use **vsnprintf()** instead sprintf().

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vprintf.html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I accepted the next one because I could just paste the code instead of clicking the link.

Comment: @user294702 Maybe clicking the link is more of a hassle, but you're not going to learn anything by just copy/pasting code. Just my 2 cents. +1 smbear

Comment: @smbear i havent read your answer & give my answer.. othervise i  really +1 your answer & dont give my answer..!!!

Comment: However he did not justify his answer he just said use instead I hope programmers give good descirption on thier answers instead of just posting links sorry if i hurt you!

Comment: @smbear i think you should tell questiner why he is wrong with sprintf & why use vsnprintf rather then just givng link..dont you..?!!

Comment: Hello World and Copy/Pasting are development breast. With all due respect to theoritical approaches, it doesn't hurt to indulge from time to time :)